# Load an MVC3 partial view with the Reveal jQuery modal plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

We have used the jQuery Reveal modal plugin throughout our application.

http://www.zurb.com/article/557/reveal-jquery-modal-plugin

Is there a way that I can load an MVC3 partial view in a modal when the modal reveals. The partial view has a submit button and when the user clicks on submit, it should submit the form and do some updates on the parent page.  I am not sure if Reveal plugin can do that. At this point I am reluctant to use any other plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

The question is: do you need to load it dynamically? or can you just include it in the page when you create it and then let the reveal plugin hide / show it?

*WARNING* This code was Stack Overflow compiled, meaning not at all ;)

For Static Loading:

```
<!-- Include the reveal javascript / css files -->
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
  <%: RenderPartial("PartialViewPathHere",andyViewModelHere) %>
</div>
```

For Dynamic Loading: Basically the same, but the content of the modal is populated on some event and retrieved through ajax.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetDialog(int someInput, ...)
{
 // Do stuff
 return View("your view here");
}
```

Page

```
<!-- Include the reveal javascript / css files -->
<script>
    // For example
    $("source").click(function(){
        $.get("/Controller/GetDialog", {/* someInput, data here...*/}, function(view){
            $(view).appendTo("#myModal");
        });
    });
<script>
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You gave me some good pointers and the solution now works.